# How to retrieve data from Junction object for indirectly related object

Tags: soql, query, lookup, relationships, junction-object

Below I'm trying to explain how the objects are linked to each other and what needs to fetch from an indirectly related object. I want to update a field on Order object based on the value of a field CPN__c which is in the Customer Part Number object. Now the scenario is somewhat like this.

**How the source object is related?**

---

```
Customer Part Number has Lookup(Product), Lookup(Account) 
Product has Lookup(Order) 
Order has Master-detail(Account)
Order has Lookup(Account) Not important.
```

**Relationships**

Objects includes in the scenario.

```
1. Account
2. Order
3. Product
4. Customer Part Number
```

> - Order has master-detail relationship with Account.
> - Order has lookup to Product.
> - Customer Part Number has lookup to Account and lookup to Product.

There is no direct link between Order and Customer Part Number objects. I need to pick a field CPN__c value and display it on the Order object's detail page.

> Any ideas will be highly appreciable.

Comment: is there a field in Order with the value of the customer part number?

Comment: I think there's something more here you didn't describe. What does it mean that there is unique CPN for each Order? Do you mean that there always is a CPN that points to the same Account and Product, that some other Orer points to ?

Comment: @BartJuriewicz It is the actual field that I need to show on the orders detail page. There is nothing more important than this. We can assume that there is a field which needs to retrieve that's it. CPN is just a code a simple text field.

Comment: @cropredy I'm trying to retrieve that customer part number from the Customer Part Number object into the Order object.

Comment: Ok, so what does point 3. mean? I mean, what is the logic behind it - How should we know what CPN should be there? Should it be CPN that points to the same Account and Product as Order? Or something else ?

Comment: Point 3 means there is a CPN for every order. Which can be retrieved by looking for acc1 with prod1. But individually there could be many CPN for prod1 and many for the acc1. With a combination like that for example. Acc1 with prod3 or prod1 with acc7 etc. @BartJuriewicz

Comment: Superman - this question is at risk for closing, you need to [edit] the question and add some specific examples of records and values

Comment: @cropredy I tried to explain it with the help of relationships. If it is still not understandable please let me know. I'll delete my question. Thanks.

Comment: Superman,  if `Order O1 has parent A4 and P2`, then does `O1.Cpn__c = the Customer_Part_Number__c that is a junction between A4 and P2`?  What if there are multiple `Customer_Part_Number__c sharing same parents A4 and P2`?  This is why we're confused as to what you are asking

Comment: @cropredy Customer_Part_Number__c is a custom object which has cpn__c. I want to fetch this cpn__c from customer_part_number__C object and show it in the order object detail page. And order has no direct relation to the customer_part_number. Each cpn__c can only be unique for a combination of account and product record. Now I want to reach to the cpn__c. Either I can go through order to product then customer_part_number__c or the other way round.

Comment: @cropredy one thing I missed and overlooked is that there is a type_number which is unique to every product. It is the only light which can help in finding the correct combination of Account and Product with cpn__c from the object customer_part_number__c.

Comment: Superman - before anyone in the Community is going to invest more time in this, I strongly suggest you use [edit] and put specific examples using data example records in your question. Please do not do it via comments, use [edit] - it will be clearer to all

Answer (score 0):

What are the relationships here?

Account : Orders = one : many

Account : Products = one : many or many : many ?

Account : Customer Part Number = one : many

Orders : Products = many : one or many : many ?

Orders : Customer Part Number = many : one or one : one ?

Products : Customer Part Number = one : one or one : many ?

Once you have the relationships defined, you should be able to update the Customer Part Number on the Product using a Process that runs a Flow. We need to know the relationships in order to determine the criteria for the Process and in order to determine the steps in the Flow.

Comment: while useful in getting clarification from OP, this isn't really an answer

Comment: I beg to differ, the text "Once you have the relationships defined, you should be able to update the Customer Part Number on the Product using a Process that runs a Flow. " sure sounds like an answer. Sorry If I put my material in the wrong place.